# Error trying HTTPresponse on an Android service

Tags: android, httpresponse

i have  a simple class that has a method calling a httpResponse, the thing is that when i call this method from a service it crashes, can anyone help me to fix my error ?

```
    public class A(){

public String detailhtml(String Url, String params)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(Url + params);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
        // validar la respuesta http es correcta
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            String HtmlString = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            return HtmlString.trim();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }//  

}
```

and this is my service where it crashes:

```
public class serviceHTTP extends Service {
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
   String Rhtml= A.detailhtml(url, parametros);
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat here ?

Comment: i think i resolved it, i used an asynktask inside the service... i thought a service would work like an asynktask... i don't know if what i'm doing is a good practice.. if anyone recommend something else or have a better idea, it will be great.